# Pass additional arguments to event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have my functions defined in an object like this:

```
_clickHandler: function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

},

attachClickEv: function(element){
  ......
  element.on('click', this._clickHandler);
},
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to pass "this" to the `clickHandler` function

I know that I could wrap that in another function like:

```
var tthis = this;
element.on('click', function(event){
  tthis._clickHandler(event, tthis);
});
```

but then I cannot unhook the function later with:

```
element.off('click', this._clickHandler);
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Actually I know about bind to, but I cant use it here because then I cannot access the element inside the click handler :)

Comment: @Alex - what about using bind, but getting the element reference from the `target` property of the event object passed into your click handler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use bind for that. Here is an example:

```
element.on('click', this._clickHandler.bind(this));

//later in the code...

_clickHandler: function(event) {

}
```

Since you're using jQuery though, you can also use `jQuery.proxy()` too. More here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy

**Update**:

To get access to the element inside the callback you would have to use `event.target` or `event.currentTarget` or do the following (*depends on what you're doing*):

```
element.on('click', this._clickHandler.bind(this, element));

//later in the code...

_clickHandler: function(element, event) {

}
```

Another way is to set the element as a property of the object like: `this.element = $('#el')` and then use that in your callback(s).

Live example: http://jsbin.com/mezuberucu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: but how do I pass the element then, if "this" references to my function?

Comment: Here is a live example: http://jsbin.com/mezuberucu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 6):

```
_clickHandler: function(x, y, event){
  // x = 1, y = 2
  event.preventDefault();
},

attachClickEv: function(element){
  element.on('click', this._clickHandler.bind(1,2));
},
```

Answer (score 3):

As said in the documentation of [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you can pass datas to your event.

> **.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )**
>
> ### data
>
> *Type: Anything*
>
> Data to be passed to the handler in event.data when an event is triggered.

So your event could look like that :

```
_clickHandler: function(event){
  var myObj = event.data.object;
  // [myObj] will be your plugin
  // [this] will be the clicked element
  // [event] will be you event
},

attachClickEv: function(element){
  ......
  element.on('click', {object : this}, this._clickHandler);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a supported browser (ES5) you can use `bind` i.e:

```
  element.on('click', this._clickHandler.bind(this);
```