# Passing this to a method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
p.num = 100;    
$('body').on('click', '.del', this.delete.bind(this));

p.delete = function(e) {
     console.log(this.num); //100
     //how can I get the .del element?

}
```

I'm trying to get the element that produced the click, but I also need access to the num property.

How can I access both types of 'this' inside my delete method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback for an event receives an `Event` object that you can use to retrieve the element on which the event was called.

```
function(e) {
    var element = $(e.target); //This is the element that the event was called on.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Disclaimer : This is the my exact answer (adapted with the current code) taken from here : [Pass additional arguments to event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331102/pass-additional-arguments-to-event-handler/28331330#28331330)*</sub>

<sub>*Yet, the question doesn't seem to be an exact duplicate (but i may be wrong).*</sub>

---

As said in the documentation of [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you can pass datas to your event.

> **.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )**
>
> ### data
>
> *Type: Anything*
>
> Data to be passed to the handler in event.data when an event is triggered.

So your event could look like that :

```
p.num = 100;    
$('body').on('click', '.del', {object : this}, this.delete);

p.delete = function(e) {
  var myObj = e.data.object;
  // [myObj] will be your plugin
  // [this] will be the clicked element
  // [e] will be you event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jquery, you can combine those functions all into one like below:

note: num is an attribute so you have to use `.attr()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.del', function() {
        var num = $(this).attr('num');
        alert('click function and num = ' + num);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" num="500" class="del">Delete</a>
```

or if you really want to keep them separate functions....:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.del').on('click', function() {
        deleteThis($(this));
    });
});
function deleteThis(element){
    var num = element.attr('num');
    alert('click function and num = ' + num);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" num="100" class="del">Delete</a>
```

also, if youre using separate functions for the `click` and the `delete`, pass the element from `click` to `delete`: pass element -  `callDeleteFunction($(this))`, and retrieve element - `myDeleteFunction(element aka $(this))`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're asking about but maybe this is what you want:

```
var p = {};
p.num = 100;    
$('body').on('click', '.del', p.delete); // don't bind to this

p.delete = function(e) {
     console.log(p.num); // here you still can call p
     // this is del DOM element

}
```